# regular expression alphanumeric characters - allowing hyphens and underscores

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a Regular Expression for Javascript that checks if a password is correct only when

- Has at least 1 number and 1 letter
- Is still valid when it has an underscore and/or a hyphen
- Must be 4-20 characters long.

Examples:

1. test123   -> Valid
2. test1    -> valid
3. 1234     ->invalid
4. test     -> invalid
5. test1_   -> valid
6. test-2    -> valid

I tried using

```
var Reg = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z-_]{4,12}$/;
```

It works in PHP, but not in Javascript, any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by '(it doesn't work) in Javascript'? What is the issue with the regex? Note that your character range is 4-12 instead of 4-20.

Comment: apparently it does work: http://regex101.com/r/qZ0pY5

Comment: just make sure you add the `/gm` modifiers

Comment: @w0lf: What? No. He's trying to validate a field, not find multiple matches in multiline text.

Comment: Could you add the piece of code where you're using the regex Doming?

Comment: @TimPietzcker You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the hyphen at the end of the character class:

```
var Reg = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z_-]{4,20}$/;
```

You can also shorten that character class:

```
var Reg = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[\w-]{4,20}$/;
```

Also, you said 20 characters, not 12. Right?

Comment: It shouldn't change anything... Because the character range is `a-z` then `-` (cannot have two ranges ending and starting with the same character).

Comment: @Jerry: Some regex engines treat `[a-z-_]` as "`a-z`, `-` or `_`" while others try to interpret both hyphens as range operators; `z-_` would be an empty range, then (or possibly an error. Will have to look it up if any JavaScript implementations are affected by this).

Comment: Thanks I tried   var Reg= /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[\w-]{4,20}$/; and it works just fine!!!